# Hoje são ou Hoje é?

Tags: gramática

Por exemplo:

1. Hoje **são** 15 de março.
2. Hoje **é** 15 de março.

Qual o uso correto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ambos

Para o primeiro caso, a frase é equivalente a quantos dias passaram desde o começo do mês.

> Hoje são 15 (dias passados) de março.

Para o segundo caso, estaríamos falando de um dia em específico

> Hoje é (dia) 15 de março.

Comment: Então ambos sirve igualmente para indicar a data em específico, ou só "hoje é"?

Comment: @DanGetz Acho que você não entendeu, com "são" é dias passados de um mês, mesmo que ambos cheguem ao mesmo "resultado" o entendimento é que em outros lugares/usos (que não datas) este valor "possa variar". Ao menos foi o que eu entendi.